# How to split a return statement in several lines to fulfill flake8 style

Tags: python-3.x, flake8

I have a function with a return statement like:

```
return apple, banana, orange, pear, grape, kiwi
```

But it exceeds the maximum number of characters that flake8 lets me (in the example I've just put a dummy example), so how should I do it?

I've tried things like

```
return apple, banana, orange,\
    pear, grape, kiwi

return apple, banana, orange,
    pear, grape, kiwi

return apple, banana, orange,
pear, grape, kiwi
```

And nothing works. The last one was accepted by flake8 but it throws an execution error.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a tuple, so you can do like this:

```
return (
    apple,
    banana,
    orange,
    pear,
    grape,
    kiwi
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't specify the error codes you're seeing -- flake8 doesn't implement any itself, but you're likely seeing codes from `pycodestyle` (either `E` / `W`)

pycodestyle accepts any of these:

```py
def f():
    return apple, banana, orange,\
        pear, grape, kiwi
```

```py
def f():
    return (
        apple, banana, orange,
        pear, grape, kiwi,
    )
```

```
def f():
    return (
        apple,
        banana,
        orange,
        pear,
        grape,
        kiwi,
    )
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer and one of the pycodestyle maintainers